# Как удалить системный файл в каталоге /data/?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Мне нужно удалять файл `i.txt` из папки `/data`. При этом *рут* у меня есть.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, Android - это Linux, так что можно просто запросить рут в шеле и удалить:

```
String command = ""; // команда на удаление
command = "rm /data/i.txt";   //например
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); // запрашивает рут
os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

Или заюзать что-то [такое](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/tree/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser).

```
if(Shell.SU.available()){
   Shell.SU.run("rm /data/i.txt"); // удаление файла
else{
   System.out.println("su not found");
```